# Подскажите сервис, в котором можно порешать алгоритмические задачи на конкретную тему

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите сервис, в котором можно порешать алгоритмические задачи на конкретную тему, имеется ввиду сервис с контестом или встроенным тестированием задачи. По типу codewars, но с возможностью выбора темы. Конкретно, меня интересуют задачи на графах.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problemset/algorithms/?search=graph

Comment: У малого в школе давали задание сначала на https://informatics.msk.ru/, теперь на https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/